# Deploy Javascript Cron Jobs and Queues on Amazon Elastic Beanstalkd

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an **Amazon Elastic Beanstalk** application currently running my **NODE.JS** app.

I have created some Queues with **kue.js** and Crons with **node-schedule**.

Since I have many commands to run the queues and crons, I find it impossible to put it on my current nodejs app.

I am willing to open a new application, the only problem is that I can only run one command.

I really don't want to open a seperate ec2 (not connected to my Elastic Beanstalk service) to run all of those.

What can I do to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Some stuff isn't clear to me what do you mean by willing to open a new application? can you describe when do you need to run those commands is it just a one-time thing when you deploy the service?  how do you run those commands?

Comment: By application I mean a new beanstalkd node.js application, and yes it's one time when I deploy the service but they supposed to be maintained by something like pm2 in case they crush.

Comment: is the Queues with kue.js and Crons with node-schedule is just a javascript scripts that you run using node or pm2?

Comment: exactly, it's a javascript in a loop just like express.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use EB(Elastic Beanstalk) you could write a docker file for the application  and EB will already detect that and ask you if this is a docker based project and it will take care of the rest, you just need  write all the scripts that you need to run before your Entry point Command CMD`npm start` like below

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine
# Sets the working directory,and creates the directory as well.
WORKDIR /app
# Install dependencies.
ADD package.json .
RUN npm install
# Copy your source code.
COPY . /app

#Run all your scripts here or simply put them to a scripts.js and run it
RUN node scripts.js

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: But what will happen when one of my nodejs application crush?

Comment: isn't pm2 is supposed to be responsible for handling that?